# MVPS Hosts file slow down the browsing significantly

Tags: host

I have been using MVPS for two weeks now now but I started seeing slow browsing and sometimes it takes so long that I end-up restart my computer and I have Premium Malwarebytes and McAfee antivirus software installed but still its really slowing down

I have download the hosts file from [here](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm)
Shall I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, it indeed speeds up your connection. check the site you are trying to access, perhaps it's URL is actually *in* the list.  PCH for example is in it, and the HOSTS file was preventing my room mate from getting his daily "publisher's clearing house" fix.